# How to display this button again?

Tags: css, sass

Really.I can't find a solution...this is what I have to reproduce..this button here ok..but with the hover effect (second button on the picture), I am lost...
I tried everything...add a skew on the link but the hover can't take. I tried the clip-path but then my after disappears...
I don't know how to proceed anymore.
I also tried to add a ::before but the hover doesn't work properly anymore.
thanks a lot in advance

[image]

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  padding: 15.5px 77px 13.6px 24px;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: #726a53;
  background: blue;

  
}

button::after {
  content: "";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      transform: skew(-13deg,0deg);
      bottom: 0;
      width: 56px;
      -webkit-transition: background-color ease-in-out .25s;
      transition: background-color ease-in-out .25s;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: 20px 15px;
      background-color: red;
 }
```

```html
 <a class="button">Learn more </a>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen on hover?

Comment: I would like it to be like my second image, transparent with borders :) Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Can you edit the HTML or not?

Comment: Just this : <a class="button">Learn more </a>

Answer (score -1):

to do what you want I think you need to use the "hover command" like this :

```css
.button {
    display: block;
    padding: 15.5px 77px 13.6px 24px;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: #726a53;
    background: blue;
}

.button:hover {
    ...  // you put here the css you want to have the result on the hover
}
```